# Why console.logs in generator appears in such order?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, generator

Having the code below, I'd like to ask 2 questions (main and secondary):
1. promise *p* is yielded before *console.log(second)* in generator function, so why *console.log(second)* logged before console.log from given promise?
2. I saw somewhere (it was done in koa framework) that returned value (see *return 'some value'*) was used in code (sent with the response back to client)... How could I console.log it in my gen function? Is it even possible?

```
var p = new Promise((resolve) => {
    resolve('should go first?');
})

var resp = p.then((first) => {
    console.log(first);
    return 'some value'; //pertain to the secondary question
})


function* gen(prom){
    var second = yield prom;
    console.log(second);
}

var it = gen(resp);

it.next();
it.next('should go second?');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. promise p is yielded before console.log(second) in generator function, so why console.log(second) logged before console.log from given promise?

what you're yielding is the promise object if you check  it's value you'll see the status is `pending`

> ..How could I console.log it in my gen function? Is it even possible?

in a `then` method you can log it

```js
var p = new Promise((resolve) => {
    resolve('should go first?');
})

var resp = p.then((first) => {
    console.log(first);
    return 'some value'; //pertain to the secondary question
})


function* gen(prom){
    var second = yield prom;
    console.log(second);   
    
    prom.then((x)=> {
     console.log(x);
    });
}

var it = gen(resp);

var first = it.next().value;
console.log(first);

it.next('should go second?');
```

Answer (score 2):

### Question 1.

1. The executor for promise `p` resolves the promise synchronously during call with value "should go first".
2. `resp` is set to the promise returned by calling `then`
   on `p`.  Note the onFulfilled function supplied to a promise is never executed in the same thread which supplies it. If the promise is already resolved, the callback will be scheduled in its own thread after the current thread completes execution.
3. `it` is set as the iterator of the generator function. Code is still executing synchronously from the top.
4. `it.next()` is called and returns the promise object `resp` (which goes unused).
5. `it.next()` is called again with "should go second" presented as the return value of yield in the generator function, which logs it to the console.
6. The code thread as posted completes execution. The onFulfilled listener for promise `p` is scheduled for upcoming execution and logs `should go first` when it executes.

### Question 2.

`some value` is currently returned from the onfulfilled listener of `p`, and as such would be be used to fullfill the next chained promise, created by calling.`then` on `resp`. If you want to pass it to the generator function,  replace `return 'some value'` with `it.next('some value')`.

### Conclusion

The bottom line is that all promises objects defined in a single piece of synchronous code are created in their entirety, with call back linkages in place, before *any* asynchronous processing of `onFulfilled` or `onRejected` functions supplied through then/.catch calls starts to takes place. This is true even if promises are resolved (synchronously) during their definition.